# EF Core - Nullable complex property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd want to be able to create an Order object without `SomeOptionalType` being defined at the creation (in db) moment.

afaik in database it has to be nullable foregin key

.NET Core 2.1 / EF Core with postgre sql driver

```
public class Order
{
    [ForeignKey("SomeOptionalTypeId")]
    public Guid SomeOptionalTypeId { get; set; }
    public SomeType? SomeOptionalType { get; set; }
}

public class SomeType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: So, if `SomeOptionalType ` can be `null` why `Guid SomeOptionalTypeId` is not nullable?

Comment: @RomanDoskoch I'm an idiot. Please write it as an answer, so I'mma accept. BTW. SomeType doesn't have to be nullable (it aint even avaliable in pre-c#-8)

Comment: `SomeType` can be value type and it can be nullable (from question it is not clear if it is value or reference type, so your code may be correct if it is value type (`SomeType?`))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SomeType? SomeOptionalType` is optional and can be `null` then `Guid SomeOptionalTypeId` also can be `null`.

Change `Guid` to `Guid?`:

```
[ForeignKey("SomeOptionalTypeId")]
public Guid? SomeOptionalTypeId { get; set; }
```